# Add gap between two Divs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a screen split in two, using two columns.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 well">
            Left Box
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 well">
            Right
        </div>
    </div>
```

I need a small (approx 10px) gap between the two columns.

http://www.bootply.com/vaOb1WdR5I

Can this be done?

Both boxes would need to reduce by 5 pix (in the above example), as I need the total width to remain.

Edit: Some ideas nearly work, but I am getting an extra Well that I don't want. With this:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">

                @Html.Action("ShowDuePayments", "Transaction")

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">

                @Html.Action("ShowRecentTransactions", "Transaction")

        </div>
    </div>
```

I get this:

[image]

The 'under' well div shouldn't be visible.

Comment: change the no. of cols as col-md-5 and then add a margin left 0f 10px

Comment: Would be nice to see the HTML output rather than a screenshot. Looks like there might be a div with class='row' inside the col-md-6 divs, hence removing the gap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of points:

1. You shouldn't add extra classes to the Bootstrap columns (that's not a hard and fast rule, but a good recommendation)
2. You are missing the container wrap.

Make changes using those rules and it looks like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="well">Left Top Box</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="well">Left Bottom Box</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="well">Right Box</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is very close to right. My only issue is that I don't want the grey background. The columns should be 'invisible'. Possible?

Comment: @Craig The gray is due to the `well` class, I only put it in as it was in your question. I've added another row without to demonstrate the difference.

Comment: Thanks @DavidG. As soon as I remove those wells, it goes back to square one. i.e. No gap. I've edited my original question with the results of the example WITH the wells. It's so close. I can't add the 'container' because I already have a parent container in my sitelayout - and thought you were only allowed one?

Comment: Do you have a well inside well in the screenshot you provided? It's hard to decode it without seeing the HTML.

Comment: Focussing on the `ShowRecentTransactions` view, it looks like it has 2 well elements inside it?

Comment: Looks like you nailed it, DavidG! Very close now. There were 'wells' in the 'ShowDuePayments'. Removing them, however, had made the left 'block' into one big well, and it's hard to differentiate between the two 'groups'. I was hoping it would be one 'invisible' column, with two well blocks inside.

Comment: Did you remove the wrong well from the left div then?

Comment: I've edited the answer to more closely match the question with 2 wells on the left.

Comment: It's so close to right. Thanks DavidG. StackOverflow is shouting at us for talking too much, so I will try fix the rest myself. But it's so much better already. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" style='padding-right:5px'>
      <div class='well'>
        Left Box
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style='padding-left:5px'>
      <div class='well'>
        Right
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/Ogrte6IQzw

If you remove the inline styling, you will have the natural spacing provided by bootstrap, which is 15px padding.

Comment: +1 Much better than mine *(deleted)*. This works because of the applied `box-sizing: border-box` to all `*` elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the class of `col-md-6` and add `width:49%`, and to the 2nd div add `pull-right` class like:

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 well">
        Left Box
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 well pull-right">
        Right
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.col-md-6{
    width:49%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to add padding to the two div tags ie:

```
.col-md-6{
    padding:5px;
}
```

This would add a bit of padding to all the sides - unless you use `padding-left` & `padding-right` and assign different class names to the divs - depending on how you want your code to be layed out.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an additional class so you only modify special column-6 elements and not all on your site. This example also uses percentage based widths as Flopet17s. You could tweak the percentage number to better fit your desired gap width.

```css
.withgap {
   width: 49%;
   margin-right:1%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 well withgap">
    Left Box
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 well">
    Right
  </div>
</div>
```